# How can i click a span in Behat?

Tags: html, testing, click, behat, mink

I am using Behat to test an third-party webshop. I have a item in the shoppingcart that i want to delete. A confirmation pop-up shows that asks me if i really want to do it. The structure of this dialog looks as following:

```
<div>
    <strong class="title">Remove item from shoppingcart</strong>

    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this product?</p>

    <div class="button-container">
        <span class="button" data-confirm="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="button alt right" data-mfp-close-link="true">No</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was able to select the span using xpath with the following code:

```
public function iConfirmTheWindow()
{
  $session = $this->getSession();
  $element = $session->getPage()->find(
  'xpath',
  $session->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath('css', 'span.button')
  );
  if (null === $element) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not find confirmation window'));
  }

  $element->click();
}
```

The selecting works, but Behat seems to be unable to click the span.

```
 supports clicking on links and submit or reset buttons only. But "span" provided
```

I need to click this item, how can i rewrite my function so that it can be clicked?

Answer (score 12):

The answer from @bentcoder doesn't make any different. It uses a different a selector to find the element, but the Minkcontext `click` functionality doesn't support clicking on `span` elements.

Which i find quite strange, because with jQuery you can add the `button` class to and `span` element and there is your button.

Context code:

```
/**
 * @Given I click the :arg1 element
 */
public function iClickTheElement($selector)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $element = $page->find('css', $selector);

    if (empty($element)) {
        throw new Exception("No html element found for the selector ('$selector')");
    }

    $element->click();
}
```

CLI output:

```
  And I click the "#new_account" element # tests/behat/features/account.feature:14
  Behat\Mink\Driver\GoutteDriver supports clicking on links and submit or reset buttons only. But "span" provided (Behat\Mink\Exception\UnsupportedDriverActionException)
```

I'm assuming that you have have a Behat driver for interpreting javascript. So i've added `@javascript` to the feature:

like so:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Create new account
  Given I am logged in as "user" user
  And I am on "/user/settings"
  And I click the ".new_account" element
```

Comment: "Which i find quite strange" - could this be because clicking an element that is not a link or a button has no effect in non-JavaScript?

Answer (score 5):

The code snippet I use is this:

```
/**
 * @Then /^I click on "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iClickOn($element)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $findName = $page->find("css", $element);
    if (!$findName) {
        throw new Exception($element . " could not be found");
    } else {
        $findName->click();
    }
}
```

As an example, I would write something like this in my scenario:

```
Feature: Test Click

@javascript
Scenario: Clicking on spans
Given I go to "http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/"
 And wait "3000"
When I click on "span:contains('behat.yml')"
 And wait "3000"
Then I should be on "http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: A little late on the party: i gave this one a try too and it works perfectly fine too!